# WPF USB card reader keyDown

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, cardreader

I have problem with reading text from card reader connected to USB.
I have method in window:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key k = (Key)e.Key;

    textBoxLogin.Text += k.ToString();
}
```

Problem is that, it simulates all pressed keys so if in my magnetic card i have something like: 
!EXAMPLE,
that would read LeftShift1LeftShiftELeftShiftX etc..
Any solution how to change it?
Btw i know i can click on textBox and then read all from card reader, but that should work with disabled textBox.

Thank u for any answers!

Comment: Can you take time to reformulate your problem because as it is it's quite difficult to understand ?

Comment: I have same problem as here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223297/concat-keydown-event-keys-to-one-c-sharp-wpf-string
read first post

Comment: Then can you use the same solution?

Comment: Downvoted : question is unclear.

Comment: Ok so one more time.
I have magnetic card reader connected to PC and trying to read string from card. I wrote method which read pressed key and putting it into textBox. Card reader works just like keyboard. SO if in card is information like: $AsD, i wil have in my textBox that values: LeftShift1 LeftShiftA s LeftShiftD (becouse it read shift + pressed button). But i want exactly same information from card in my textbox. I can do it only when i make textBox active, but that should work with disabled textbox.

Comment: @user1617141 Can you edit your question instead of reformulating it in a comment ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no easy way to convert keys to a string. If you really want to get the text from the Window_KeyDown callback, I think you'll have to code your own converter.

The source of your problem comes from the input : why does the card contains a series of keydown events rather than directly the characters ?

Comment: Card contains only character.
There is example directly from card:
;:<>4076451634?
But all i can read from it using keyDown is
; LeftShift: etc.